# What is the fastest way to rename a PostgreSQL schema/tables includes the views, the functions / stored procedures, indexes

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, stored-procedures, database-design

Need help here: I have a schema which is called `techno_marino` and I would to replicate the entire schema with its table/indexes/views/stored procedures.

However I would like it to have different schema name called something like `techno_qwert` which means everything inside this schema such as index/views/stored procedure will automatically update the schema into new one.

What is the fastest way to achieve that?

Thank you

Comment: Do you have the install files (`.sql / .spl`) for the objects already?  If so, you could logon and connect to the database you want to install to `(\c MyDatabaseName)`.  Then run the install files but with unqualified object names.